# HTML button to next page is not working in Flask development server

Tags: python, html, flask

I have two pages `index.html` having code as following

```
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"  name="text" placeholder="Enter Text" rows="6"></textarea>
            
          </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

    </form>


    <button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3  col-sm-1"></div>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='upload.html'"
 value='click here'>
</div>
<button>
```

It has `js` and `css` in `head`. As you can see there is a button to go to `upload.html` page, which contains code to upload file as following

```
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
```

If I open `index.html` page in a browser and click on `click here` button it redirects me to the intended page, But when I run Flask app and try to click on this button it gives `404 error`. Right now I haven't created any Flask method for this file. I have tried to add absolute path to `upload.html` file and `./upload.html` and almost every method to create a button mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link). I also tried to redirect it to a blank page and `index.html` itself but every time the error is same. It is only giving me error with local `HTML` files if I give an address of some website it redirects me to it. Can someone help me with what I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a route and point the input element to the new page. Right now that won't work within Flask because the app does not "see" the upload.html page.

so you would first create a route in your routes.py or app.py

```
@app.route(methods=["GET", "POST"])
def file_upload():
    return render_template("upload.html")
```

and then in your `index.html` you would point the input to this route:

```
<input type=button href="{{url_for('file_upload')}}" value='click here'>
```

just remember, `url_for` as a function points to the function name, not the html template itself. So here you call `url_for` which in turn calls `file_upload` which in turn renders `upload.html`.

Comment: now it's not giving any error as it is returning `status 200` but it's not doing anything when I click on button. I have tried it with default route, `/upload` route and with and without `GET,POST` methods

Comment: @Woox, Please run flask in debug mode and let us know what happens